Date dimension showing the wrong data
When i use the date field from my date dimension, shows the value of every day on the dim date... Seems like a relationship problem, but i cant find the problem.
The data showing all the dates on the "Data Completa" field, not only the 21/03/2024:

The relationship:

The Script to create the dim_Tempo_Criacao:
dim_Tempo_Criacao = 
VAR startDate = MIN(FatoChamados[Data Criação])-365
VAR endDate = MAX(FatoChamados[Data Criação])+365
VAR dates = CALENDAR ( startDate, endDate )
RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS (
    dates,
    "Ano - Número",             YEAR ( [Date] ),
    "Mês - Número",     MONTH ( [Date] ),
    "Mês - Nome",       FORMAT ( [Date], "MMMM" ),
    "Mês - Abrev.",            FORMAT( [Date], "MMM" ),
    "Ano Mês",       FORMAT( [Date], "YYYYMM" ),
    "Ano/Mês",       FORMAT( [Date], "YYYY/MM" ),
    "Dia",       FORMAT( [Date], "DD" ),
    "Data Completa",       FORMAT( [Date], "DD/MM/YYYY" ),
    "Quarter",          "Q" & FORMAT( [Date], "Q, YYYY" ),
    "Quarter Sort",     FORMAT ( [Date], "YYYY/Q" )
)

Someone have an idea why this is not working?

Can you show the date columns in the actual powerbi tables?
